# How to create a table layout in which it is inside linear layout programmatically

Tags: android, tablelayout

sorry for posting this...i searched about this and i cant find anywhere .
I want to create `TableLayout` with n rows and 4 columns(`EditText`)...
the first line of app will be like this::

```
Enter the number of rows : 3
```

and below this there will be a button in which clicking, 3 rows and 4 columns(`EditText`) must be created.Like this...

```
------   ------   ------   ------
------   ------   ------   ------
------   ------   ------   ------
```

How can I do this??

Comment: @Merlevede thats ok...i dont have answer on that link...how shall i do it dynamically...that is user must enter number of rows..

Comment: There's the answer!!! We are here to help, not to do your job. Try harder.

Comment: @Merlevede I have a doubt..

Comment: @Merlevede How to add TableLayout inside Linear Layout...

Comment: Can i create array of TableRow object